# What defines if a stock is able to settle in CREST

Tags: stocks, united-kingdom, nasdaq

I'm based in the UK.  Using Hargraves Lansdown platform I've purchased various shares on the NASDAQ exchange.  Today I decided I would like to purchase some Atlassian shares which are also on the NASDAQ exchange.  However they were not available through the HL platform.

I questioned HL about this and they responded:
"Unfortunately Atlassian Corp plc (TEAM) does not settle in Crest and we are therefore unable to trade them. "

I'm curious what determines where a stock can settle in CREST?
Is there a list of CREST compatible stocks?

Comment: That surprises me, as they use Computershare as transfer agent which certainly seems to use CREST.  But I'm not an expert in this area at all, hopefully someone who is will happen by.

Comment: What is CREST and why might HL or another broker choose not to use it?

Comment: HL also do not list FNDR which is another NASDAQ GS stock.

Comment: I had the same problem with TEAM and just found out HL also can't trade NASDAQ:ARM, but Freetrade can trade both - that's got to be pretty embarrassing for HL. If Freetrade can solve this problem, then HL should be able to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm having the same issue with AJ Bell, and I got this reply when asking for a list of stocks which settle in CREST:

"Unfortunately, there is not a list of CREST settleable securities that we can send to you. We use something called the Crest Gui which is a system that allows us to check each stock an individual basis. However, we pay a fee to CREST for this service. Therefore, it would be a case of having to check with us on an ad-hoc basis I’m afraid."